# ajax refresh part of page error

Tags: javascript, refresh, reload

for some reason, when my ajax reloads part of a page, I get this weird bug that when you click on anything else, the page reloads. My page is at http://thomaswd.com/organizer/dashboard. Go to the sidebar and create a new class. Then look at the right, and click on one of the accordion headings. How do I fix this?Thanks!

Comment: the page does not seem to reload...

Comment: i know, the ajax reloads part of the page, but the page reloads when you click on a heading after creating a new class

Answer (score 0):

You have set your form to submit the form values to the **addclass.php** file :

```
<form target="hiddenframe" action="addclass.php" method="post" 
                                  onsubmit="hideaddcourse(),refreshclasses()">
```

PHP is executed on the server side & hence your page reloads.

Comment: i know that it refreshes, and thats why i make it reload part of the page with ajax